# Swift 3 - how to determine that key and value type in run time?

Tags: dictionary, swift3, nsdictionary

How can we find out at runtime that key and value type of a NSDictionary variable at runtime?

e.g.

```
var dict:NSDictionary = [:]

// How to find out what the type is for the key and value?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is extremely rare that you should be using `NSDictionary` in Swift. There is no "key and value type" for an `NSDictionary`. Each individual element can potentially have a different type (ObjC dictionaries are only consistent by convention, not by requirement). Generally if you need this, you're on the wrong path. You almost always want to use Swift's `Dictionary` rather than `NSDictionary`.

That said, the answer in this case is that the key is `AnyHashable` and the value is `AnyObject`. That's all the type information you have. Beyond that, you'd just have to interrogate the objects.

Comment: Thanks Rob. What about Dictionary? How can I query the type of key or value (say for output to the screen)?

Comment: @Boon Tell us exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I want to query a dictionary and output the type of its key/value to screen.

Comment: Does `print(type(of: myDict))` suffice?